# what is the meaning of 'Return Along' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of 'Return Along' in this sentence?

> price decisions are one of
>   the most important decisions of management because it affects
>   profitability and the companies’ **return along** with their market competitiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a very well written sentence—it has a few issues with singular and plural consistency among other things.

But *return along* is not a phrase.

In parsing the sentence, you should look at it like this:

> . . . the (companies' return) along with their market competitiveness.

---

The *companies' return* means how much the companies got back from their original investment.

A common acronym for this is *ROI* (or return on investment).

From [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/returnoninvestment.asp):

> Return on Investment (ROI) is a performance measure used to evaluate the efficiency of an investment or compare the efficiency of a number of different investments. ROI tries to directly measure the amount of return on an particular investment, relative to the investment’s cost. To calculate ROI, the benefit (or return) of an investment is divided by the cost of the investment. The result is expressed as a percentage or a ratio.

---

So, what the passage is saying is:

> Setting the price of a product is an important management decision because its price affects three things: (1) profitability, (2) return on investment, and (3) market competitiveness.

Comment: this sentence is from a ISI paper